# Run A User Oracle Procedure That Uses Other Schema

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Say UserA created an Oracle 11g procedure named SomeProc, SomeProc perform DML/DDL queries on UserB schema, how to accomplish this without granting UserA access on UserB needed objects? example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure UserA.SomeProc IS
BEGIN
UPDATE UserB.SomeTable SET SomeField = 1;
END;
```

Running the above example will throw exception asking to grant UserA updating UserB table.

The idea of my question is, I don't want UserA to be able to SELECT TABLE from UserB schema directly from application code, instead, UserA should only be able to execute his own Procedure where that procedure itself is the one who can access UserB objects, it is a sort of security approach we need to avoid UserA from running his own custom queries from application code.

Answer (score 0):

> without granting UserA access on all UserB objects

Lucky you, that's exactly how it works. You can't grant privileges on **all** objects; there's no (for example)

```
grant select on all userA tables to userB;
```

You have to grant privileges on every object separately.

Therefore, the answer to your question is simple: grant only required privileges on desired objects to another user, e.g.

```
grant select                 on dept to userb;
grant select, insert, update on emp  to userb;
```

Comment: Actually this is the technique am using now, I didn't mean by "all objects" to grant on all, i meant to say the hassle of granting each needed object.

The idea of my question is, I don't want UserA to be able to SELECT TABLE for example from UserB schema directly from application code, instead, UserA should only be able to execute his own Procedure where that procedure itself is the one who can access UserB objects, it is a sort of security approach we need to avoid UserA from running his own custom queries from application code.